# Why printing out e_name.get() works, but printing the variable assignment to this same .get() doesn't?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter

I'm trying to get a name from an user with Entry() function from Tkinter and then assign it to the variable Name, so that I can use it later. To check if the assignment works, I call the ready function, which makes Label with my variable. When i use 'e_name.get()' in 'command=' it works but when i use 'name' it doesn't. I guess I've messed up in order of code lines, but I'm not sure.

Here is the python code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e_name = Entry(root, width=50)
e_name.pack()
name = e_name.get()

def ready():
    test = Label(root, text= name)      #and this works >>> test = Label(root, text= e_name.get()) 
    test.pack()

ready_button = Button(root, text="Next", command=ready)
ready_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calling the `e_name.get()` right after the entry is created will get an empty string as you haven't input anything yet.

Comment: `name` will not be updated when you enter something in `e_name` entry.  If you want such feature, you should change `name` to instance of `StringVar` and assign it to the `textvariable` option of `e_name` entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare name as global to access it outside of ready() function:

1) Initialize name = '' before def ready()

2) Add global name as first line in ready()

3) Add a new Get Name button

4) Add a new label below Get Name button to display the global name variable upon clicking Get Name button

5) Add function get_name() which uses global name to configure the new label with the last value stored by the ready() function.

It isn't pretty, but this working code demonstrates how to use name outside of ready function thanks to global.  Test it by editing entry value, clicking Next button, then clicking Get Name button.  The Get Name clicks will change the label directly under it to reflect the last value stored in global name by the ready() function.

If you edit the entry value and press the Get Name button it will not display the new value (it will continue to show previous value) in the new label until you click the Next button, because that is where global name variable is changed.  I think this is the behavior you desire:

Here is the full working code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

e_name = Entry(root, width=50)
e_name.pack()

name = ''

def ready():
    global name
    name = e_name.get()
    test = Label(root, text= name)      #and this works >>> test = Label(root, text= e_name.get()) 
    test.pack()

def get_name():
    global name
    test2.configure(text= name)

ready_button = Button(root, text="Next", command=ready)
ready_button.pack()

name_button = Button(root, text="Get Name", command=get_name)
name_button.pack()

test2 = Label(root)
test2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I have just submitted new code to reflect a global approach that will allow you to take advantage of the name variable outside of just that one localized ready() function.

Comment: Great!  Please accept (up-arrow) the answer if you are satisfied that it works.  Thanks!